# Como usar o $ do jquery no wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

O wordpress indica usar o seguinte código:

```
( function( $ ) {
    // Your code goes here
} )( jQuery );
```

Mas eu estou usando o zurb foundation 6, e creio que isto não vá ser o suficiente pra roda-lo junto com o Jquery do wordpress, visto que o próprio foundation possui varias chamadas usando $ dentro dele.

Como eu posso fazer as chamadas do $ serem passadas para o Jquery do Wordpress automaticamente?

Comment: Já testou usar o `noConflict()` do jQuery? Por exemplo, para mudar o $ simples do jQuery para outro, coloque no código, por exemplo, `var $a = jQuery.noConflict();`... assim os comendos do jQuery passaram a ser $a em vez de apenas $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O wordpress faz isso por segurança, para não acontecer carregares outras bibliotecas que usam o `$` e que não são jQuery.

Se tens certeza que isso não acontece, e que a biblioteca que precisas usar tem mesmo de ter o `$` declarado, então basta teres `window.$ = jQuery;` depois do script onde carregas o jQuery no wordpress, ou seja antes de carregares essa biblioteca que precisas.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Pode usar normalmente aqui dentro.
  $('#element').hide(); //exemplo
});
```

Outra forma seria só atribuindo a variável $:

```
$ = jQuery;
```

Depois desta linha poderia utilizar normalmente. A primeira opção é mais segura para ser utilizada no Wordpress.